# SBT installed but not showing in IntelliJ external model list

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, intellij-plugin

I have installed sbt plugin version 1.0.4 and I’m trying to import a starter scala project built on Scala 2.12.4. When i try to the import that project, the IntelliJ external model list doesn’t show sbt. 
Where am i going wrong? 
Thank you in advanced.

Im using a macbook air on OS X El Capitan 10.11.16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps try with the latest version of the IntelliJ and the SBT plugin. Hope this helps!

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5007-sbt

Answer (score 2):

Remove and install the Scala plugin again works for me.